# Как подключить Material Design в проект при помощи gulp

Tags: gulp, material-design

Пакет material установлен командой npm install @material/textfield
Он, понятно, установился в node modules.
Как его подключить в проект при помощи Gulp?

Answer (score 1):

В документации же ясно написано

- скрипты `import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';`
- стили `@import "node_modules/...";`

Comment: эта документация для React

Comment: Вот не надо, так подключаются ассеты не только в реакте.